# Encountering a problem when trying to insert JSON data into my postgres database - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express

I'm having a problem when i try to save my JSON data into a database. Right now, i have this code here:

My service that retrieves and cache data from an API with the given parameter `cep`:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const NodeCache = require('node-cache'); 

const myCache = new NodeCache();
const pool = require('../database/index');

async function verificaCache(cep) {
  const value = myCache.get(cep);

  if (value) {
    return { city: value, message: 'Data from the cache' };
  }

  const resp = await axios.get(`https://viacep.com.br/ws/${cep}/json/`);

  myCache.set(cep, resp.data, 600);

  return { city: resp.data, message: 'Data not from the cache' };
}

module.exports = verificaCache;
```

My route using the service:

```
const express = require('express');

const cityRouter = express.Router();

const verificaCache = require('../services/VerificaCacheService');

cityRouter.get('/:cep', async (request, response) => {
  const { cep } = request.params;

  try {
    const data = await verificaCache(cep);

    response.status(200).json(data);
  } catch (error) {
    response.status(400).send({ message: 'Erro no retorno do CEP' });
  }
});

module.exports = cityRouter;
```

It works with out problems:
[image]

Here that comes the problem. When i try to insert the data into my database implementing this code into my service:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const NodeCache = require('node-cache'); 

const myCache = new NodeCache();
const pool = require('../database/index');

async function verificaCache(cep) {
  const value = myCache.get(cep);

  if (value) {
    return { city: value, message: 'Data from the cache' };
  }

  const resp = await axios.get(`https://viacep.com.br/ws/${cep}/json/`);

  myCache.set(cep, resp.data, 600);
  
  // begins here the code to insert data into the database
  const {
    logradouro, complemento, bairro, localidade, uf,
    ibge, gia, ddd, siafi,
  } = resp.data;

  const values = [cep, logradouro, complemento, bairro, localidade, uf, ibge, gia, ddd, siafi];

  const sql = 'INSERT INTO public.city(cep, logradouro, complemento, bairro, localidade, uf, ibge, gia, ddd, siafi) VALUES ?';

  await pool.query(sql, values); // ends here the code to insert data into the database

  return { city: resp.data, message: 'Data not from the cache' };
}

module.exports = verificaCache;
```

It doesn't insert anything! And i tried to put only `city` instead of `public.city` and it still doesn't work.

Here is my `index.js` file for the connection:

```
const { Pool } = require('pg');

const pool = new Pool({
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 5432,
  user: 'postgres',
  password: '1234',
  database: 'eureka',
});

pool.connect((err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Erro connecting to database...', err);
    return;
  }
  console.log('Connection established!');
});

pool.end((err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Erro to finish connection...', err);
    return;
  }
  console.log('The connection was finish...');
});

module.exports = pool;
```

And my Database without any data:
[image]

I created the table `city` directly from the `dbeaver`.

As you can see, my application is connected to the database:
[image]

I'm a beginner and i would appreciate some help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to be using any library that handles dynamic mapping of your parameters to the required ordinal format into the query itself(like [pg-parameterize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-parameterize)) so the line:

`const sql = 'INSERT INTO public.city(cep, logradouro, complemento, bairro, localidade, uf, ibge, gia, ddd, siafi) VALUES ?';`

and more specifically the `VALUES ?` part shouldn't be doing anything useful. Change that to:

`const sql = 'INSERT INTO public.city(cep, logradouro, complemento, bairro, localidade, uf, ibge, gia, ddd, siafi) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10)';`

as the `pg` npm package is using ordered parameters for parameterized queries.

Checkout the "Parameterized query" section in the [docs for queries](https://node-postgres.com/features/queries).

### EDIT:

You're either inserting the new record or getting an error. There is no other option. If you don't see any new record in the db after refresh, then you're just **swallowing** the error result in your code. As you're going the `async/await` promise route, the code `await pool.query(sql, values);` will throw if something goes wrong.

Then, in your caller:

```
cityRouter.get('/:cep', async (request, response) => {
  const { cep } = request.params;

  try {
    const data = await verificaCache(cep);

    response.status(200).json(data);
  } catch (error) {
    response.status(400).send({ message: 'Erro no retorno do CEP' });
  }
});
```

you catch the error. Check what the `error` object in the catch block is holding and you'll see what's wrong.

Comment: I forgot to say, but i tried that too, i did put my values as ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10), but it still didn't work

Comment: @werliney Do you get any error? And did you try the solution above without providing the schema in the query - `const sql = 'INSERT INTO city(cep, logradouro, complemento, bairro, localidade, uf, ibge, gia, ddd, siafi) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10)';`? 

`public` is the default schema, so you shouldn't provide it.

Comment: No, i don't get any errors. And yes, i tried that and it still didn't work, sadly

Comment: You were right. I was wrong that i didn't console.log(error) to see what was happening. The problem is that i was calling pool.end() before inserting data into the database. Thank you for the help